# Chat - Users list not showing up, reporting error

Tags: quickblox

I rebuilt the chat app example from scratch and everything was going along correctly until I try to load the users list. As I try to load, no names show and an alert view pops up with just 'error.' Any question on how to solve this? I used almost the exact code from the chat example. Here's what I did:

```
@implementation UsersViewController


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];    
[QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];
[QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:@"%@" password:@"%@" delegate:self];
[QBUsers userWithExternalID:46732 delegate:self];

self.users = [NSMutableArray array];
self.selectedUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
self.paginator = [[UsersPaginator alloc] initWithPageSize:10 delegate:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Fetch 10 users
[self.paginator fetchFirstPage];
```

Comment: please post Xcode logs. I run this sample and it works without any errors

Comment: Hey, the sample (and the one I rebuilt) runs just fine, it just reports an error via UIAlertView. This is a bit confusing to me, because it suggest that I make an incorrect request somehow. Does this have to do with the calling method? I'm a novice, so I find certain things difficult.

Comment: Look at Xcode logs and post them

Comment: I actually fixed the problem, but it says 'forbidden user'.

Comment: 'forbidden user' means that you can't create any object without user login

Comment: Can you please expand on that? I've been registering 'users' through the app and they show up on my chat list, but the 'forbidden user' pops up. How can I fix this?

Comment: it means you have to call [QBUUser login... in order to create some object

Comment: Can you take a look at what I did (I edited my comment)? I'm still having a little trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way:

```
[QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];
[QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:@"%@" password:@"%@" delegate:self];
[QBUsers userWithExternalID:46732 delegate:self];
```

all these requests are asynchronous, not synchronous

you have to wait until each request will be finished in order to perform next one

Comment: I saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723295/terminating-app-while-signing-up-a-new-user-in-quickblox-from-ios-application. Is this similar to what you are talking about?